# Using ASP.NET Core 6 having issue to connect to Oracle database using TCPS protocol

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oracle11g, .net-6.0

After upgraded my application from .NET Framework to ASP.NET Core 6, I am having issues connecting to an Oracle database using TCPS protocol, while existing application is working fine.

I get this error:

> Network Transport : SSL failure in parsing wallet location

I have already setup the required setting and proper wallet location

[image: I updated this Oracle Setting]

What other thing could I do?

Comment: Are there any spaces in the directory path?

Comment: I suggest you could re-check the  ODP.NET library version to make sure it support .net 6.

Comment: @Pmdba: no there is no spaces in the directory path.
I am using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core v3.21.120